# Autohotkey to cycle through active program windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer, autohotkey

I have this autohotkey file. When I press F2, it toggles through any windows explorer tabs I have open and keeps it in focus / sends it to the top. If no file explorer windows are open, it opens one up

[image]

Code

```
F2::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class CabinetWClass
    Run, explorer.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers, ahk_class CabinetWClass ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe explorer.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class CabinetWClass ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return
```

The problem I have is I can't make it work for other applications. Many times I have multiple chrome windows open, or multiple excel files open, and I can't cycle through them like I can here with a different hotkey. I tried replacing the `.exe` file names, `groupnames`, doesn't work with anything but windows explorer here

Comment: I answered my own question here https://superuser.com/questions/1265437/windows-shortcut-key-to-maximize-all-chrome-windows-or-any-specific-application

Answer (score 1):

```
F5::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Run, chrome.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers5, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers5, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return
```

This is the basic variant autohotkey I'm using to cycle through chrome windows and put them up top.

full answer here: [Windows shortcut key to maximize all chrome windows or any specific application](https://superuser.com/questions/1265437/windows-shortcut-key-to-maximize-all-chrome-windows-or-any-specific-application)