# Windows shortcut key to maximize all chrome windows or any specific application

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

Is there a shortcut to maximize all chrome windows or *[insert any application here]* button with windows?

There's some similar ones like pressing `WIN+SHIFT+M` that maximizes *all* windows in your taskbar, and then there's `WIN+1` which maximizes / opens the program sitting on taskbar slot 1

For reference, this is taskbar slot 1,2,3,4

[image]

Comment: Then why not you try `Win+4` according to your screenshot?

Comment: If a program can have multiple windows open (Excel, Word, Chrome), using WIN+4 requires *alot* of clicking navigation and or button pressing. Its also not that button friendly for my fingers. In this 9 min video, this guy explains why WIN+4 is not efficient. This video (time stamp 8:10 minute mark) explains all the inefficient pitfalls with using this key combo https://youtu.be/OqyQABySV8k?t=490. Some of the windows shortcut commands/UI /animations for win+4 are just *terribly* made in windows 7 to windows 10. The only solution really is autohotkey to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of tweaking and testing some workflows, this is what I settled with. I ran a combination of both phrase-express (any macro program works here) and autohotkey here, so I can have an extremely flexible layout

```
F1 → Binded to WIN+1 key
F2 → Binded to WIN+2 key
F3 → Binded to Win+4 key
F4 → Binded to Win+4 key
```

For F5 to F7 keys, I used autohotkey

```
F5::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Run, chrome.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers5, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers5, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return

F6::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
    Run, cmd.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers6, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe cmd.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers6, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return

F7::
IfWinNotExist, ahk_class QWidget
    Run, anki.exe
GroupAdd, kjexplorers7, ahk_class QWidget ;You have to make a new group for each application, don't use the same one for all of them!
if WinActive("ahk_exe anki.exe")
    GroupActivate, kjexplorers7, r
else
    WinActivate ahk_class QWidget ;you have to use WinActivatebottom if you didn't create a window group.
Return
```

F5 to F7 uses the same variant autohotkey, I just changed up the `groupnames`, the `.exe files` , and the `ahk_class` names.

This is how I organize the structure of my windows taskbar

[image]

So I press

- F5 (3 times), and it pushes each chrome window I have up to the top of each of my 3 monitors.
- F6 and I can quickly pop out whatever command prompts I have open, one command prompt for gulp commands, and one for git, independent of any IDE.
- F7 twice to quickly add some new flashcards

I can restructure F1 F2 F3 F4 to whatever app I'm currently using. Anything that goes here I only keep one window per app at a time. Like I only run one firefox window (to watch tutorial youtube videos), only one running application of PHPstorm, etc.

Demonstration of F6 key in action (command prompt)

[image]